# How to Select cities from drop down while booking tickets using robot framework

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I am new to robot framework and i tried to automate booking sites and when i tried to select cities from Yatra.com website but unable to select cities and dates to book the tickets

*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${url}    https://www.yatra.com/

${browser}    chrome

*** Test Cases ***
Logintest

```
Open browrser ${url} chrome

maximize browser window

click element    xpath://*[@id="themeSnipe"]/div/div/div[1]/button

select from list by label    flight_origin    New Delhi
select from list by label    flight_destination    Bangalore
```

Can someone help me to select cities from dropdown and also select dates.

Comment: What error are you getting? also please post the error details